# Cannot see any figure on SE site from today

Tags: support, bug

It just happened to me I cannot see anymore any pictures (figures) posted on SE sites?!
I switched browsers, Firefox, Chrome etc and no success!
In place of figures I only see links where there are not accessible either due to some "https" failure etc.
Note that is was working just couple of days ago, this problem was noticed today and still exist!

Comment: I checked http://www.imgur.com/ is blocked "now" in my place. If this the source problem. Any workaround?

Comment: Cause: yes. Solution: get it unblocked or use a vpn.

Comment: also `stack.imgur.com` is totally blocked here.

Comment: @PatrickHofman How do I get it unblocked? Any trustworthy freeVPN?

Comment: You need to talk to your workplace to relax the firewall rule. Do you really want people here to recommend workarounds that can get you in trouble with your workplace?